# How can I find out how nginx was "./configure"d for Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, package-management, nginx

`nginx` is my web server of choice. It doesn't provide loadable module support as of yest, therefore everything has to be compiled and linked into the final binary.

How can I find out which configuration - particularly for the additional modules, the package maintainer chose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nginx -V` will show you configure arguments

http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine